# How to figure out what number a record is, when in date order

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel project I have a `Policy` model that looks like so:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use App\Notifications\PolicyRequiresApproval;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Policy extends Model
{
    const STATUS_PUBLISHED = 'published';
    const STATUS_PENDING_REVIEW = 'pending review';
    const STATUS_SENT_FOR_REVIEW = 'sent for review';
    const STATUSES = [
        self::STATUS_PENDING_REVIEW,
        self::STATUS_PUBLISHED,
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'user_id', 'name', 'content', 'status',
    ];

    /**
     * The user who authored the policy.
     */
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the audits for this policy.
     */
    public function audits()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PolicyAudit::class, 'policy_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    /**
     * Get all of the versions for this policy.
     */
    public function versions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(PolicyVersion::class, 'policy_id', 'id');
    }

    /**
     * Get the current version.
     */
    public function currentVersion()
    {
        return $this->versions()->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->first();
    }

    /**
     * Get the most recent approved version.
     */
    public function currentApprovedVersion()
    {
        return $this->versions()
            ->whereNotNull('approved_at')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->first();
    }

    /**
     * Get the URL to preview the policy for administrators.
     */
    public function getPreviewUrlAttribute()
    {
        return route('thanos.policies.show', $this);
    }

    /**
     * Send a policy to the policy administrator for approval.
     */
    public function sendForReview(Policy $policy)
    {
        User::role(['admin'])->get()
        ->each(function ($user) use ($policy) {
            $user->notify((new PolicyRequiresApproval($policy))->delay(now()->addSeconds(10)));
        });

        $this->update(['status' => self::STATUS_SENT_FOR_REVIEW]);
    }
}
```

As you can see there are versions of a policy.

My policy versions table schema looks like so:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreatePolicyVersionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('policy_versions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('policy_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
            $table->longText('values');
            $table->boolean('is_major_change')->default(0);
            $table->dateTime('approved_at')->nullable();
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('approved_by')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('policy_versions');
    }
}
```

My question is as follows: if I have five versions of a policy in date order and I select a policy version, how could I say "you are on version n of x for this policy"?

Would it be best to add a `policy_version_number` and just increment it each time a new version is created?

This feels like a dumb question but initially I was just going to use the version id but this would actually be incorrect.

Comment: " if I have five versions of a policy" You have multiple database entries for the same item?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As every time a user saves the model I create a new version (if it changes).

Comment: That is not how a database should work, but if you want to have an arbitrary piece of data stored in a record, yes you will need a new column.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have a polies table and a policy_versions table. In the versions table I store a aerialized version of the model. Then if a user want to revert to a version I overwrite the policy record with the data in the selected policy. How else would I achieve versioning? I was trying to take inspiration from WordPress which has page revisions.

Comment: It was also based on a Laravel package called Versionable.

Comment: Ok I didn't read your question closely enough, I thought you were dealing with your "policies" table here. Do you have a separate `PolicyVersion` model?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I have a PolicyVersion model yes, every time theres an update I create a new instance of PolicyVersion that has the policy id, a version number (given your feedback) and a values field which is just a long text field to store a representation of the Policy whose data was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [listen to the model's](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events) events and automatically populate the column when the model is created. To do that, implement the `boot` method in your `PolicyVersion` model:

```php
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function (PolicyVersion $item) {
        $max = PolicyVersion::where('policy_id', $item->id)->max('policy_version_number');
        $item->policy_version_number = $max + 1;
    });
}
```

Untested, but should do the trick.